# How to read data from excel file using loop in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to go through all the cells of an Excell sheet using Matlab, but my code breaks

```
s1 = 'A2';
s2 = 'F2';
x2 = xlsread('text.xlsx',[s1, ':', s2])
for i=1:3
  s1 = s1+1;
  s2 = s2+1;
  x2 = xlsread('text.xlsx',[s1, ':', s2])
end
```

Comment: What is your question, please clarify.

Comment: Reading Excel file is slow. IMHO it's better to read the whole sheet at once into a temporary matrix and get the required range in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You want increase the index of the rows:

```
for i=2:5
  s1=['A',num2str(i)];
  s2=['F',num2str(i)];
  x2 = xlsread('text.xlsx',[s1, ':', s2])
end
```